# How to make my json WCF to work

Tags: c#, json, wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-rest

I have struggled a lot spent quiet a lot of time but unable to make it work, after spending hours now I am able to see the metadata but unable to successfully call the operation. below are the steps and code.

1. Create WCF Service library project.

Now code.

**Service contract and DataContract**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

using System.Text;

namespace JsonWCFTest
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IJsonService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,UriTemplate = "data/{id}")]
        Product GetProduct(string id);
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "product")]
    public class Product
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

}
```

**Service.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace JsonWCFTest
{
    public class JsonService:IJsonService
    {
        public Product GetProduct(string id)
        {
            return new Product {Id = " you have entered " + id};
        }
    }
}
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>  
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="service.svc" service="JsonWCFTest.JsonService"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <services>
      <service name="JsonWCFTest.JsonService" behaviorConfiguration="jsonTestServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="jsonTestEndPoint" behaviorConfiguration="jsonTestEndPointBehavior" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" contract="JsonWCFTest.IJsonService"/>        

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>      
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="jsonTestServiceBehavior">       
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>       
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="jsonTestEndPointBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

when I am using this url

> `http://localhost/service.svc/data/1`

it is giving me this below error in internet explorer

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /service.svc/data/1

Comment: I'm curious why you're using WebInvoke for a GET? Why not use WebGet() and set the WebMessageFormat to Json)?

Comment: @Mark B,  no idea becase I was following a Walk through I have to look into this. If you can suggest kindly suggest me the best pracise.

Comment: I think you always use WebGet() for all GET requests. Use WebInvoke() for all other HTTP "verbs" like POST, DELETE or PUT. You can still use the ResponseFormat attribute for JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are connecting to the wrong address. With the config file you have set up you should connect to

```
http://localhost/jsonTestEndPoint/data/1
```

You need to use `BaseAddress` + `EndpointAddress` + `FunctionAddress` to get the full url.

---

I may be a little rusty, if the above address did not work, then the address will be

```
http://localhost/service.svc/jsonTestEndPoint/data/1
```

Comment: thanks alot for your help. 2nd suggested link worked, but one v small question again, how can I use this link in my Win forms app or Windows Phone mango app

Comment: You may need to open a new question for that if this does not answer your question, but simply "visiting" the web page using a class like [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), the result the page returns is the JSON which you can then parse with a JSON library of your choice.

Comment: The term for what you are doing is a [RESTful web service](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/) (look at "Expose directory structure-like URIs", look familiar?)